# list assignment to global variable

Tags: python

Please look at this code:

```
def x():
    a.append(1)

def y():
    print a

a = []
x()
y()
```

which outputs:

> [1]

and this:

```
def x():
    a = [1]

def y():
    print a

a = []
x()
y()
```

which outputs:

> []

I don't understand why I can't explicitly set global list variable `a` in a function, without using list methods, like `.append()`, but just setting the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second example, `a = [1]` is creating a new local variable named `a`, not referencing the global variable `a`. In order to reference the outer scoped `a` you could do:

```
def x():
    global a
    a = [1]
```

See the Python documentation for the [global keyword](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt), specifically:

> It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global,
>   although free variables may refer to globals without being declared
>   global.

In your first example, `a` uses the global variable because you are referencing a variable that does not exist as a local in the `x()` function, but does exist in the global variables.

Answer (score 2):

In version 1, when you use `a` in `x` and `y` Python "goes looking" for an `a` to use, and finds it in the outer scope.

In version 2, you define a local `a` inside `x`, and assign to that; there's no need for Python to look in other scopes. If you want to use the "outside `a`", you have to be explicit about your intentions:

```
def x():
    global a
    a = [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

the second example isn't a global variable. You are declaring a new local variable `a`, and assigning it to `[1]`